# How to append logs from different users to the same text file in a SQLite table?

Tags: java, sqlite, logging, log4j2

I am using log4j2 in order to have an audit trail file that stores logs for every action a user does.

All of these users are connected to an SQLite database table. Currently, all my logs are stored in a `audit.log` file but I want it to be stored in the database so that every user's logs are appended to the same `audit.log` file.

My `log4j2.xml` is as follows (which is basically the same as the official log4j site simple fileAppender example is):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn" name="MyApp" packages="">
  <Appenders>
    <File name="auditFile" fileName="logs/audit.log">
      <PatternLayout>
        <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
    </File>


  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="error">
      <AppenderRef ref="auditFile"/>
    </Root>
    <Root level="info">
      <AppenderRef ref="auditFile"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working. So, my current `log4j2.xml` didn't suffer any relevant changes but here it is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn" name="MyApp" packages="">
  <Appenders>
    <File name="auditFile" fileName="./audit.log">
      <PatternLayout>
        <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
    </File>

  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="error">
      <AppenderRef ref="auditFile"/>
    </Root>
    <Root level="info">
      <AppenderRef ref="auditFile"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

In order to get it to work, this is the code I've written for my application (in order to log, I just call the `saveLog(String context)` method):

```
public void saveLog(String context) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
        Class.forName(classForName);
        Connection connection = null;
        logger.info(context);

        try
        {
          // create a database connection
          connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionPath); 
          //connectionPath is the path to my database

          Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
          statement.setQueryTimeout(30);  // set timeout to 30 sec.

          File file = new File("audit.log"); 
          FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);

          PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE OR REPLACE shell SET audit=? WHERE name='shell.txt'"); 
          //shell is the name of my sqlite table

          ps.setBinaryStream(1, fis, (int)file.length());

          ps.executeUpdate();
          ps.close();
          fis.close();


          System.out.println("SQL save done");
        }
    catch(SQLException e)
    {
      // if the error message is "out of memory", 
      // it probably means no database file is found
      System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    finally
    {
      try
      {
        if(connection != null)
          connection.close();
      }

      catch(SQLException e)
      {
        // connection close failed.
        System.err.println(e);
      }
    }
}
```

Everytime I load my application, this is the code I use to make sure every user is working with the same `audit.log` file:

```
public void loadLog() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, IOException {

        Class.forName(classForName);
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionPath);

        String sql = "SELECT audit FROM shell";

        PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery();

        while (resultSet.next()) {
          File audit = new File(fileOutputPath2);
          FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(audit);

          byte[] buffer = new byte[1];
          InputStream is = resultSet.getBinaryStream(1);

          while (is.read(buffer) > 0) {
            fos.write(buffer);
          }
          fos.close();
        }
        conn.close();

        System.out.println("SQL Load Done");
    }
```